# How do I write this script's results to a file?

Tags: powershell, directory, output

Basic question as I'm learning powershell. At the moment I have a script that give me the output of a directory in a nice clean format. I want to write the results to file rather than to the console. I can't seem to figure out the correct use of Out-File. I've tried it in the script and tried it as an extension when running it. Any help would be appreciated.

```
get-childitem "A:\data\set1" -recurse | where {$_.extension -eq ".mp3"} | % {
 Write-Host $_.FullName}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to use Write-Host:

```
get-childitem "A:\data\set1" -recurse | 
  where {$_.extension -eq ".mp3"} | 
  % {$_.FullName} | 
  Out-File ./list.txt
```